# About NSMutableArray add NSArray issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to below effect,but I don't kown how to use NSMutableArray combine NSArray More than two?

1.my code

```
for (int i=0; i<[DateSortArry2 count]; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<[DateSortArry2Copy count]; j++) { 
            NSString *sectiondateStr2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[DateSortArry2Copy objectAtIndex:j]];    
            if ([[DateSortArry2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:sectiondateStr2]) {  
                [Arry addObject:sectiondateStr2];   
            }
        }
        [SumArry addObjectsFromArray:Arry];
        [Arry removeAllObjects];
    }
```

2.my code Result

```
SumArry:(
"20130227",
"20130227",
"20130227",
"20130226",
"20130226",
"20130226",
"20130225",
"20130225")
```

3.I want the results

```
SumArry:((
    "20130227",
    "20130227",
    "20130227",
    ),
    (
    "20130226",
    "20130226",
    "20130226",
    ),
    (
    "20130225",
    "20130225"
    ))
```

Comment: Hey! why the downvotes? Got to help people. Upvoting to counteract the downvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code repeatedly fills and empties the same array by adding its elements, but you need to preserve the structure with additional instances of `NSArray`. So, use a new `NSArray` for each section.

```
for (int i=0; i<[DateSortArry2 count]; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *section = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int j=0; j<[DateSortArry2Copy count]; j++) { 
        NSString *sectiondateStr2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[DateSortArry2Copy objectAtIndex:j]];    
        if ([[DateSortArry2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:sectiondateStr2]) {  
            [section addObject:sectiondateStr2];   
        }
    }
    [SumArry addObject:section];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!sartak!you are Right!

Answer (score 2):

You can either store a reference to another array (or any type of object) in your array:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:otherArray];
```

Or concatinate the arrays.

```
[myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:otherArray];
```

Both of which are documented in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). By the looks of it the first approach is what you want since you want to have `NSArray` of `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
please tell me if it works.
thanks

```
NSString *str = @"";
    for (int i=0; i<[DateSortArry2 count]; i++)
     {
           if (str isEqualToString:[DateSortArry2 objectAtIndex:i])
           {
                return;
           }
           else
           {
                NSMutableArray * Arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                str = [DateSortArry2 objectAtIndex:i]
                for (int j=0; j<[DateSortArry2Copy count]; j++)
                {
                    if ([[DateSortArry2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:str])
                    {
                        [Arry addObject:str];
                    }
                }
                [SumArry addObject:Arry];
                [Arry removeAllObjects];
            }
    }
```